# Laravel - there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table - using multiple uniques

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

I'm getting this error in Postgres 7.2:

> Invalid foreign key: 7 ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "holiday_items" (SQL: alter table "holiday_bookings" add constraint "holiday_items_parent_holiday_item_id_foreign" foreign key ("parent_holiday_item_id") references "holiday_items" ("id") on delete cascade)

Here is the migration I'm trying to run:

```
Schema::create('holiday_bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->uuid('booking_id')->index();
    $table->integer('booking_version')->index();
    $table->uuid('parent_holiday_item_id')->nullable();

    $table->unique(["id", "booking_id", "booking_version"]);

    $table->foreign('parent_holiday_item_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('holiday_items')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('quotation_id')->references('id')->on('quotations')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here are the fields in the `holiday_items` table with a unqiue constraint:

```
Schema::create('holiday_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->integer('booking_version')->index();
    $table->uuid('booking_id')->index();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(["id", "booking_id", "booking_version"]);

    $table->foreign(['booking_version', 'booking_id'])->references([
        'booking_version',
        'id'
    ])->on('bookings')->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

What is wrong with my foreign key assignment in the `holiday_bookings` migration?

Comment: Did you try by using onUpdate('cascade') for parent_holiday_item_id field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the id column as the primary key, this is where this column get uniqueness

in your migration:

```
 $table->uuid('id');
  $table->primary('id');
```

and there will be no need for setting this column as unique in your migration

Comment: Actually @f7n, this other answer is more accurate.

Comment: adding primary() removed the error, but I don't want the table to be unique on the id alone, but a combination of the `id` and `booking_version`. is that possible? that's why i added this line: `$table->unique(["id", "booking_id", "booking_version"]);`

Comment: see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: I've just tested this and adding `primary()` to the ID also adds a unique constraint to the field, but I need to be able to add multipe records with the same `ID` but different `booking_versions`. what can I do?

Comment: you should make the primary constraint consist from more than a column: $table->primary(['id', 'booking_versions']);

Comment: see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `holiday_items.id` column doesn't have a unique constraint.

Modify it like this:

```
Schema::create('holiday_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->unique();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
    // ..
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the unique constraint be defined here:  `$table->unique(["id", "booking_id", "booking_version"]);`

Comment: @f7n not really. That unique constraint is for the composition of the 3 column values, meaning that you can repeat two of them and mofify a third one for the combination to still be unique.

Comment: I've just tested this and it's not how it works. With the 3 column unique constaint, AND the `primary()` on the `id` field, I cannot repeat two of the values, as the unique contraint on the `id` fails.

Comment: @f7n yes, if you add the `primary()` clause aswell, that value must be unique. Keep in mind that in your original code that's not the case, that's why I commented that in response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen when you get a many-to-one relationship wrong. Say one user can own many comments, but your DMBL said `comments.user_id - user.id`, a one-to-one relationship. That would generate a foreign key relationship in SQL, which must target a primary key or unique key column.

So instead of DBML and SQL like this:

```
Ref: comments.user_id - user.id
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("id") REFERENCES "comments" ("user_id");
```

Change it to this:

```
Ref: comments.user_id > user.id
ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id");
```